# Facebook Javascript SDK API limit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook-graph-api, facebook-java-sdk

I have the following JS snippet:

```
$('.profile-link').each(function(){
      link = $(this)
      FB.api(link.attr('data-uid'), function(response) {
          link.text(response.name)
      });
})
```

And I have like 20 links of the class 'profile-link', the above code seems to work only for the first 3-4 links. So, my guess is that Facebook has a limit on number of API requests per second, is that right? If not, then how to solve the above problem?

Answer (score 0):

The only unofficial info I could find is 600 calls per 600 seconds from a particular access token. you can find more info at the following threads:
http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=56950
http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=23561
http://www.quora.com/Whats-the-Facebook-Open-Graph-API-rate-limit